# where to download cool animations for testing?

Tags: animation, testing

I am looking for some sites where I can download some short clips (5-20seconds) for testing purposes of video import routines.

Does anyone has some data sources for wmv, mpeg, mov, etc. ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.open-video.org/

http://www.archive.org/

http://reefvid.org/

Or just take some short vids with a digital video camera (or digital camera), import them onto your computer.

You can convert video files at http://www.zamzar.com/ to any format from any format.

Answer (score 2):

Youtube, and convert it with ffmpeg

Or film trailers are often in mov (imdb: http://www.imdb.com/Sections/Trailers/ )

Or game trailers, gamershell / gamespot / ...

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this few days ago and here is best one I found:

http://www.jhepple.com/support/sample_movies1.htm

16 different files (two original samples), rather small sizes, covering most of popular formats.

Answer (score 0):

[MetaCafe](http://www.metacafe.com/) allows you to download videos. I have some clips that I use for testing which are downloaded from there.

Answer (score 0):

Some HD clips:

- http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/musicandvideo/hdvideo/contentshowcase.aspx - Windows Media Audio and Video 9 Series, 1080p WMV files
- http://www.apple.com/quicktime/guide/hd/ - H.264 in Quicktime containers
- http://www.w6rz.net/ MPEG-2 Transport Stream Test Patterns